Node Install: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined
So I am using the latest version of node and npm as for today (10 April 2024):

Now using node v21.7.2 (npm v10.5.0)

I want to install my current project into -g globally accessible by running this:
npm i -g .

But there is this error:

npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.

This is the full error log:
0 verbose cli /Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/bin/node /Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.5.0
2 info using node@v21.7.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 0ms
5 timing config:load:file:/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/alvinstefanus/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 3ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 4ms
17 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm i .
21 verbose argv "i" "--global" "."
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 6ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/alvinstefanus/.npm/_logs/2024-04-10T13_10_42_482Z-
25 verbose logfile /Users/alvinstefanus/.npm/_logs/2024-04-10T13_10_42_482Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 4ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 0ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 timing idealTree:init Completed in 3ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly placeDep ROOT undefined@ OK for:  want: file:../../../../../Documents/Projects/DGLS CLI
38 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 3ms
39 timing idealTree:node_modules/undefined Completed in 0ms
40 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 3ms
41 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree Completed in 9ms
43 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 10ms
44 timing command:i Completed in 19ms
45 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
45 verbose stack     at [diffTrees] (/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:348:20)
45 verbose stack     at Arborist.reify (/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:164:27)
45 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:153:5)
45 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/Users/alvinstefanus/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.2/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5)
46 verbose cwd /Users/alvinstefanus/Documents/Projects/DGLS CLI
47 verbose Darwin 23.4.0
48 verbose node v21.7.2
49 verbose npm  v10.5.0
50 error Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.
51 verbose exit 1
52 timing npm Completed in 183ms
53 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1712754642648
54 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:diffTrees 1712754642664
55 verbose code 1
56 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/alvinstefanus/.npm/_logs/2024-04-10T13_10_42_482Z-debug-0.log

I have tried to delete the package-lock.json and node_modules folder, and reinstall all the dependencies, but it is still giving me the same error. I tried to ask ChatGPT and other AI, they said there is something wrong with the npm / node version. I still cannot find the solution.
Please help

add name property to package.json
